# show that $(n+1)^{n+1} \ge (n+2)^n$

Tags: analysis

show that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ holds  $(n+1)^{n+1} \ge (n+2)^n$. I know that it's no so hard, but still I can't do that. I tried to do that using binomial theorem, was it a good idea ?

I need some hints or solution.

Comment: Mathematical Induction maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently, we want to prove that $(n+1)\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^n \ge 1$.

By the Bernoulli Inequality, we have $\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^n\ge 1-\frac{n}{n+2}$, that is, $\frac{2}{n+2}$. Multiplying by $n+1$, we get a number $\ge 1$.

Comment: did you change $\frac{n}{n+2}$ into 1, because it's smaller than 1?

Comment: The Bernoulli Inequality says $(1+t)^n \ge 1+nt$ for $t\gt -1$. Here we use $t=-\frac{n}{n+2}$, Then when we multiply $\frac{2}{n+2}$ by $n+1$, we get $2\frac{n+1}{n+2}$. For $n\ge 0$, we have $\frac{n+1}{n+2}\ge \frac{1}{2}$, which gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\binom{n}{k} \frac1{(n+1)^k} \le 1
$$

so

$$
\bigg(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\bigg)^n = \bigg(1 + \frac1{n+1} \bigg)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac1{(n+1)^k} \le n+1
$$